# Undefined reference to static methods members of a class?

Tags: c++

I have this compiler error, complaining about the static functions. I don't know if the issue pertains to the enumeration or the actual classes

```
// enumeration
enum SOURCE  { file, network};
//class declaration
class A
{
public:
    static const double findValue(std::string nme);
    static const double getValue(SOURCE ds);
};

// class definition
const double A::findValue(std::string nme)
{
    ...
    ...
    return some_double;
}

const double A::getValue(SOURCE ds)
    double val;
    switch(SOURCE::ds)
    {
        case SOURCE::file:
            ......
            break;
        case SOURCE::network:
            .....
            break;
        default: 
            break;
    }
}

   // use
void myValue()
{
double det1 = A::findValue("DNS");
double det2 = A::getValue(SOURCE::file);
}
```

Why does my compiler complain about the two static methods being undefined ?

The error:

```
In function 'System::myValue()' : System.cpp : (.text._ZN11System8myValueEv[_ZN11.....]+0x1d): undefined reference to 'A::getValue(SOURCE)'
```

similar error for the other method of findValue().

Comment: Did it occur to you that providing the actual complaint the compiler shares with you might be a good idea?

Comment: `enum SOURCE = { file, network}` What is this? Why are you showing broken code that does not reproduce the problem? All I see here are several syntax errors, a couple of semantic errors, a bunch of irrelevant code and a _redefinition_ .... no lack of definition. Sort it out!

Comment: `A::getValue()` is not the same as `A::getValues()`.  Likewise for `A::findValue` vs. `A::findValues()`

Comment: @Carlton  I fixed the typos...that is not the issue. In my code all the name are correct. I was just retyping the code differently, as I work on different computer for development

Comment: That use of const is strange.  But I don't know whether it is the problem or whether it is just meaningless excess syntax.  What was supposed to be the meaning of returning a const double as opposed to a double?

Comment: I removed the const "for assignment operator overloading" , but the problem persists... am using the enumeration properly ? Is access to static member functions inside another class method definition, possible ?

Comment: Question is still broken. Present your [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or we _cannot_ help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code.  Firstly, you define the function `A::findValue()` twice.  Secondly, in the body of `A::getValue()`, you need to write the switch statment like this: `switch(ds)`, not `switch(SOURCE::ds)`.  Thirdly, as @JSF pointed out, returning a const primitive by value is unusual (though technically legal), but probably not what you intended to do.

Edit: `A::getValue()` needs to return a value as well.

Comment: And none of these things presents the described error. The question is broken.

Comment: @Carlton  , thanks, in trying to make the code simple from my actual code, I made the typos. There are no definition twice. there is just one.  I removed the constants in the return primitive, and the error remains. The mistake relates to the static methods. Is it possible to use static methods anywhere in the code as long as they do not attempt to work with non-static class member variables "object variables"

Comment: Your static methods should work anywhere, but any compilation unit in which they get called needs to find them, that means you have to include the right headers, expose the right namespace, etc.